# xparse with underscore and optional argument

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, xparse

I need a macro which handles its input as follows:

1. `\foo A` > #2 = A
2. `\foo{A}` > #2 = A
3. `\foo(B)` > #3 = A  (round brackets)
4. `\foo_m A` > #1 = m, #2 = A
5. `\foo_m{A}` > #1 = m, #2 = A
6. `\foo_m(B)` > #1 = m, #3 = B  (round brackets)
7. `\foo_{m}(B)` > #1 = m, #3 = B (and analogous for `(B) = {A}` )

Bonus points, if also `\foo_m {A}` and `\foo_m (B)` (with an additional space) are mapped like 5 and 6, resp. (Remark: If I left an argument out in the above listing, then #? = NoValue is desired.)

I tried the following definition

```
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{t_ m g d()}
```

but this does not work in all cases (not in the 3. and 4.).

Comment: Too complex a syntax.

Comment: `t` is for a "*-like" switch, it doesn't absorb tokens as argument.

Comment: I agree with egreg.  Now, some of what you want could be now done with the argument specification `e{_} g d()`, perhaps with an additional step that if `#2` and `#3` are both missing then a further argument should be grabbed.